# Appending html without losing events

Tags: javascript, html, append

In order to preserve my event handlers i know that i need to preserve the elements node.

the goal is to add the html to the page without rewriting the html on the page.

I really have no idea what to do here, i have never needed to do this before.

Here is what i am trying to add to the page without losing the handlers of my current elements.

```
var tagged_element_ = document.createElement(tag);
tagged_element_.innerHTML = "<" + tagged_element_.tagName + " id='" + id + "'></" + tagged_element_.tagName + ">";
```

Normally i would just do `element.innerHTML += tagged_element_.innerHTML;`
but that's not working.

This is a javascript question, do not mention or supply any forms of JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).

```
// Create a new paragraph element, and append it to the end of the document body
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: Yeah i thought that to but i am pretty sure i am using it wrong.. The html comes out like <div><div id="myid"></div></div> when it should only be <div id="myid"></div>

Comment: WOOO I GOT IT!!! with your guidance !!! :D YES!!! :3 so happy thnk you so much :D!!! especially for the documentation!